# Add Percent Sign To Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, percentage

I have a very simple progress bar im making and everything works except for one thing...the percent sign. My code is below and my question is how would add a percent sign to this without messing up the script. - [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGjkf/)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="Assets/IMG/Roz.png" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Apache Testing Server</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #ProgressWrap {
        height:30px;
        width:300px;
        border:1px solid #222;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;  
    }

    #ProgressStat {
        height:30px;
        width:0%;
        background-color:#9CF;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }

    #ProgressPer {
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        z-index:1000;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML = 0;

    var Change = setInterval(function() {
        var Per = document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML;
        ++Per
        if(Per == 101)
        {
            clearInterval(Change);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML = Per;
            var Bar = document.getElementById('ProgressStat');
            Bar.style.width = Per + '%';    
        }
    }, 50);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="ProgressWrap">
        <div id="ProgressPer"></div>
        <div id="ProgressStat"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGjkf/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change these two lines:

```
var Per = document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML.replace('%','');
```

and

```
document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML = Per.toString() + '%';
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGjkf/2/).

There's nothing wrong with your code but it doesn't really follow javascript style guidelines. Also, it's not necessary to take the innerHTML value in your calculations. Here's another version to consider going forward.

```
var pct = 0,
    change = setInterval(function () {
    ++pct;
    if (pct == 101) {
        clearInterval(change);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ProgressPer').innerHTML = pct.toString() + '%';
        var bar = document.getElementById('ProgressStat');
        bar.style.width = pct + '%';
    }
}, 50);
```